# configuring sites in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, servermanager

I am trying to connect into a **remote** IIS Server and to configure its
Sites via C#.
I am using an object called ServerManager for this operation here is my code:

```
ServerManager manager = new OpenRemote("10.1.2.23"); //IIS ip address
SiteCollection managerLst = manager.Sites;
```

after the second line i am getting the following error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-    803546CE3344} from machine 10.1.16.152 failed due to the following error: 80070005 10.1.2.23.
```

**EDIT:**
when trying the same code on localhost the process seems to work perfectly 
i think that i have a problem with permissions but i don't know how to add the username and password via ServerManager object.

Comment: Did you Google `80070005`? That should give you a very good hint.

Comment: you are using com component that not registered on computer run cmd as administrator and type c:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe path of com dll or ocx and press enter

Comment: @EmranSadeghi i typed c:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe in the cmd and i got some error about registering the module

Comment: you must specify dll or ocx COM path after c:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe as arguman

Comment: could you please type the command exactly (as it appear in your computer) cause after regsvr32.exe command i am getting an error

Comment: c:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe c:\DllOrOcxPath.dll, where DllOrOcxPath.dll is you'r module that add as reference in your project